# my matrix is not showing complete in pdf,

Tags: math-mode, arrays

code is here

```
 \[
    \setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0}
    \begin{pmatrix}
    \begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
        {x + \cosh \left[ {2t} \right]}&0&{\frac{{ - 3x + \sinh \left[ {2t} \right]}}{{\sqrt 2 }}}&0&{ - \frac{{x + \sinh \left[ {2t} \right]}}{{\sqrt 2 }}}&0\\
        0&{x + \cosh \left[ {2t} \right]}&0&{ - \frac{{ - 3x + \sinh \left[ {2t} \right]}}{{\sqrt 2 }}}&0&{\frac{{x + \sinh \left[ {2t} \right]}}{{\sqrt 2 }}}\\
        {\frac{{ - 3x + \sinh \left[ {2t} \right]}}{{\sqrt 2 }}}&0&{\frac{1}{2}\left( {1 + 9x + \cosh \left[ {2t} \right]} \right)}&0&{\frac{1}{2}\left( {1 + 3x - \cosh \left[ {2t} \right]} \right)}&0\\
        0&{ - \frac{{ - 3x + \sinh \left[ {2t} \right]}}{{\sqrt 2 }}}&0&{\frac{1}{2}\left( {1 + 9x + \cosh \left[ {2t} \right]} \right)}&0&{\frac{1}{2}\left( {1 + 3x - \cosh \left[ {2t} \right]} \right)}\\
        { - \frac{{x + \sinh \left[ {2t} \right]}}{{\sqrt 2 }}}&0&{\frac{1}{2}\left( {1 + 3x - \cosh \left[ {2t} \right]} \right)}&0&{\frac{1}{2}\left( {1 + x + \cosh \left[ {2t} \right]} \right)}&0\\
        0&{\frac{{x + \sinh \left[ {2t} \right]}}{{\sqrt 2 }}}&0&{\frac{1}{2}\left( {1 + 3x - \cosh \left[ {2t} \right]} \right)}&0&{\frac{1}{2}\left( {1 + x + \cosh \left[ {2t} \right]} \right)}
        \end{array}
    \end{pmatrix}
    \]
```

Comment: How much sense does an array inside a matrix make?

Comment: Please turn this into a minimal working example.  And what does this have to do with biblatex?

Comment: last two column are missing in pdf

Comment: @marmot last two coloumn are missing?

Comment: @Teepeemm plzz help me to overcome this problem

Answer (score 1):

it is simple to lost in your code fragment. i try to clean up only first three row, other i left to you that you clean-up others rows on the similar way as i do in the first three rows...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}
    \[\setcellgapes{3pt}
      \makegapedcells
\begin{pmatrix}
 x + \cosh[2t]   & 0 & \mfrac{-3x + \sinh[2t]}{\sqrt{2}}  & 0
    & - \mfrac{x + \sinh[2t]}{\sqrt{2}} & 0      \\
0 & x + \cosh[2] & 0 & - \mfrac{- 3x + \sinh[2t]}{\sqrt{2}}  & 0
    & \mfrac{x + \sinh[2t]}{\sqrt{2}}            \\
0 & x + \cosh[2] & 0 & - \mfrac{-3x + \sinh[2t]}{\sqrt{2}}  & 0
    & \mfrac{x + \sinh[2t]}{\sqrt{2}} 
\end{pmatrix}
    \]
\end{document}
```

**edit:**

- package `nccmath` is used for medium size fractions (`\mfrac`) in the matrix
- package `makecell` is used for (unusual) determining vertical space between matrix rows
- note, the matrix is very wide, so it can happen that it will not be within text width. if this is a case, it might help to use math environment `mmatrix`, i.e.:

  ```
  \left(\begin{mmatrix}  % <--- observe double m
  <content of matrix>
        \end{mmatrix}\right)
  ```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First of all to better show the whole matrix in your pdf sheet, I set the side margins to `1in` with the `geometry` package:

```
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
```

After I have used the `nicematrix` package with the  same strategy as on page 13 of the manual and of which I also enclose a screenshot.

[image]

The MWE output is:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\begin{document}
\[\begin{pNiceMatrix}
x + \cosh[2t] & 0 & \dfrac{-3x + \sinh[2t]}{\sqrt{2}} & 0
    &-\dfrac{x + \sinh[2t]}{\sqrt{2}} & 0\\
    \noalign{\kern.5mm}
0 & x + \cosh[2] & 0 & -\dfrac{- 3x + \sinh[2t]}{\sqrt{2}} & 0
    & \dfrac{x + \sinh[2t]}{\sqrt{2}}\\
    \noalign{\kern.5mm}
0 & x + \cosh[2] & 0 & -\dfrac{-3x + \sinh[2t]}{\sqrt{2}} & 0
    & \dfrac{x + \sinh[2t]}{\sqrt{2}} 
\end{pNiceMatrix}\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a very bulky matrix with repeating entries. So you may typeset it as

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
 \[
    \begin{pmatrix}
        a&0&b&0&-e&0\\
        0&a&0&b&0&e\\
        b&0&c&0&d&0\\
        0&b&0&c&0&d\\
        -e&0&d&0&f&0\\
        0&e&0&d&0&f
    \end{pmatrix}
    \]
where
\begin{align*}
a&=x + \cosh \left[ {2t} \right]\;, &
b&=\frac{{ - 3x + \sinh \left[ {2t} \right]}}{{\sqrt 2 }}\;,\\
c&=\frac{1}{2}\left( {1 + 9x + \cosh \left[ {2t} \right]} \right)\;, &
d&=\frac{1}{2}\left( {1 + 3x - \cosh \left[ {2t} \right]} \right)\;,\\
e&=  \frac{{x + \sinh \left[ {2t} \right]}}{{\sqrt 2 }}\;,&
f&=\frac{1}{2}\left( {1 + x + \cosh \left[ {2t} \right]} \right)\;.
\end{align*}    
\end{document}
```

[image]

This solves the problem and makes the readers a bit happier. Of course, you could write it as block matrix of `2x2` matrices to further improve the presentation,

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\diag}{diag}
\begin{document}
 \[
    \begin{pmatrix}
     A & B & E\\
     B & C & D \\
     E & D & F \\
    \end{pmatrix}
\]
where $A=\diag(a,a)$, $B=\diag(b,b)$, $C=\diag(c,c)$, $D=\diag(d,d)$,
$E=\diag(e,-e)$ and $F=\diag(f,f)$ with
\begin{align*}
a&=x + \cosh \left[ {2t} \right]\;, &
b&=\frac{{ - 3x + \sinh \left[ {2t} \right]}}{{\sqrt 2 }}\;,\\
c&=\frac{1}{2}\left( {1 + 9x + \cosh \left[ {2t} \right]} \right)\;, &
d&=\frac{1}{2}\left( {1 + 3x - \cosh \left[ {2t} \right]} \right)\;,\\
e&=  \frac{{x + \sinh \left[ {2t} \right]}}{{\sqrt 2 }}\;,&
f&=\frac{1}{2}\left( {1 + x + \cosh \left[ {2t} \right]} \right)\;.
\end{align*}    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It may be better to say $A=(x+cosh[2t])I_2$, etc.  And maybe $E=diag(1,-1)(x+sinh[2t])/\sqrt2$.